# counting shopping cart 2d Array items in asp-classic

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, shopping-cart, multidimensional-array

I have a shopping cart that using 2d array `Cart(3, 20)` to store user shop in a session.
It storing data like this:

```
 Cart(0,0) = Product_ID
 Cart(1,0) = Product_Name
 Cart(2,0) = Product_Price
 Cart(3,0) = Product_Qty
```

I want to count Items based on product_id ( we have not repetitive product_id)
I found a function here:

```
Function UniqueEntryCount(SourceRange)

  Dim MyDataset
  Dim dic
  Set dic=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

  MyDataset = SourceRange

  For i = 1 To UBound(MyDataset, 2)
   if not dic.Exists(MyDataset(0, i)) then dic.Add MyDataset(0, i), ""
  Next


  UniqueEntryCount = dic.Count
  Set dic = Nothing


End Function
```

But one problem is remain, When my Cart is empty, it show me 1

How can solved it?

Comment: You  say you 'found' this code: I wouldn't use it. It is flawed as you saw for yourself, but it also counts only unique product IDs (I don't know if that is what you want). So: 1 time P.ID 42 and 3 times P.ID 97 will result in a count of 2.

Comment: yeah i found it here in "stackoverflow"

Answer (score 0):

An unitialized fixed array (Dim a(i, j)) contains i * j empty elements; your

```
if not dic.Exists(MyDataset(0, i)) then dic.Add MyDataset(0, i), ""
```

will pick up and count the first empty item. Demonstrated in code:

```
  Dim afCart(3, 4)
  Dim dicPID : Set dicPID = countPID00(afCart)
  Dim aKeys  : aKeys      = dicPID.Keys
  Dim vKey   : vKey       = aKeys(0)
  WScript.Echo "A", dicPID.Count, TypeName(vKey)
  Set dicPID = countPID(afCart)
  WScript.Echo "B", dicPID.Count

  afCart(0, 0) = "ignored"
  afCart(0, 1) = 4711
  afCart(0, 2) = 4712
  afCart(0, 3) = 4711
' afCart(0, 4) = "not initialized/Empty"

  Set dicPID = countPID(afCart)
  WScript.Echo "C"
  For Each vKey In dicPID.Keys
      WScript.Echo "", vKey, "=", dicPID(vKey)
  Next

Function countPID00(afCart)
  Dim dicRVal   : Set dicRVal = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  Dim MyDataset : MyDataset   = afCart ' waste of ressources
  Dim iRow
  For iRow = 1 To UBound(MyDataset, 2)
      If Not dicRVal.Exists(MyDataset(0, iRow)) Then
         dicRVal(MyDataset(0, iRow)) = "" ' loss of info; will pick up Empty item
      End If
  Next
  Set countPID00 = dicRVal
End Function ' countPID00

Function countPID(afCart)
  Dim dicRVal : Set dicRVal = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  Dim iRow
  For iRow = 1 To UBound(afCart, 2)
      If Not IsEmpty(afCart(0, iRow)) Then
         dicRVal(afCart(0, iRow)) = dicRVal(afCart(0, iRow)) + 1
      End If
  Next
  Set countPID = dicRVal
End Function ' countPID
```

output:

```
A 1 Empty
B 0
C
 4711 = 2
 4712 = 1
```

Comment: I confused, WScript.Echo?! :-s